# How to send HTML form data to wp_mail function on wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a custom html form on WordPress and placed it using HTML widget

```
<form id="form">
    <label for="fname">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..">
   <label for="contact">Contact number</label>
    <input type="tel" id="contact" name="phone" placeholder="Your contact number..">
     <label for="subject">Description</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="msg" placeholder="Tell us your requirements.." style="height:100px"> 
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
  </form>
```

and here is my js code

```
function myFunction() {
var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var Contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
var Message = document.getElementById("subject").value;
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&email1=' + email + '&contact=' + Contact + '&message=' + Message;
if (name == '' || email == '' || Contact == '' || Message == '') {
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
} else {
// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxjs.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
alert(html);
}
});
}
return false;
}
```

Now I want to send mail using this form data so **How can I send email using WordPress wp-mail.php**

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when there are a lot of plugins that achieve the same functionality?

Comment: personally, I would give the form an ID, use jquery to send that data through AJAX to a custom formhandler.php on submit, and just use the wp_mail function in that formhandler. that way you don't need to have an update on your page when you submit.

Comment: also - Why use a plugin? this would take about 20 minutes to achieve.

Comment: @yogZ i dont want to do any it with any plugins

Comment: @Stender $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
 is this code is correct

Comment: well that is some of it. but you are on the right track.

Comment: https://example.com/?name=Nitin+tiwari&email=nitin%40gmail.com&phone=9174614465&msg=acsdvsvs&captchaenable=captchaenable&g-recaptcha-response=03AOLTBLTUfmoBxQP23Avw06RW5sZVUFp2x-cRcWL8pcUYGGsSdZF2g4sLvDo1WbAlLJ53Qzn5ilzvCBoGU2jqrtqMZqmHfSuw7fNhCrQzojv8iPyBTyu8C   @Stender after submiiting form my url becomes this and it redirects to my sites 404 page

Comment: You have not added the e.preventDefault() etc. also, be sure that the path to your ajaxjs.php is correct. and that file will be needed to code in php.

Comment: right now I fail to see that your `myFunction` is actually being called.

Comment: @Stender sorry i forgot to add calling of myfunction here but i have done on my code . actually  i have placed my php file in wordpress directory and inserting these code using insert header and footer plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to make some changes in your HTML and javascript and have do add few PHP code :

1) Change in form tag

`<form id="form" method="post" action="">`

2) Add a hidden field in the form with action name

`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_form_submission">`

3) add ajaxurl in functions.php file where you have enqueued your js file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your function' );

function enqueue_my_frontend_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'frontend-scripts.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    $variables = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );
    wp_localize_script('my-script', "jsObj", $variables);
}
```

4) In your ajax call, change this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: jsObj.ajaxurl, // this will get ajax url
    data: $( "#form" ).serialize() , // send your form data with serialize mode
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
    }
});
```

4) Add ajax actions in theme's functions.php file :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_form_submission', 'my_form_submission_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_form_submission', 'my_form_submission_callback');

function my_form_submission_callback(){

    $data = $_POST;

    $html = $_POST['message'];

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    wp_mail("toemail@gmail.com", "Some subject", $html, $headers);

}
```

This way you can get ajax data and pass html  wp_mail() function.

Check this link for whole demo : https://dev.to/shwetadanej/ajax-calls-in-wordpress-front-end-2g09

Comment: where should i place my ajax.php file i mean in which directory of wordpress ?

Comment: You do not have to put ajax.php anywhere. It is already built-in wordpress core.
We just have to use it.

I am guessing this is front-end, so you need to localize ajaxurl and use it in javascript.
I am making few changes in script. Please check

Comment: still not working and after submitting form i am redirected to 404 page . I have added all these code

Comment: Is it in you local environment or live ? I can help you with this.

Comment: it is on live site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205503/discussion-between-nitin-tiwari-and-shweta-danej).